# PYTHON - TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Olá, estou tendo esse retorno de erro ao tentar executar o seguinte loop:

```py
for p in p:
    for q in p:
        if p != q:
            arrFreq.append(p - q)
```

OBS: "p" é um array que contém frequências de um áudio. A ideia final desse `for` é armazenar a diferença entre as frequências. O "`if`" é pra não passar pelo mesmo valor no array. Por exemplo, tem que calcular a diferença da de `p[0]`, `p[1]...` Não pode calcular `p[0]` com `p[0]`.

Comment: eu não sei o que você queria com esse código - mas ele tá muito errrado.
se as variáveis estivessem certas no "for", você teria um `arrFreq` com o quadrado do número de frequencias da sua amostra original, com as diferenças entre todas elas, como em uma tabuada - o que obviamente não iria servir pra nada.

Comment: Se você tiver dois arrays do Numpy do mesmo tamanho, pra subtrair um do outro e ter um novo array, é só usar  o "-"  - nem precisa de nenhum for:  `diferencas = p -q `

Answer (score 1):

Você está sobrescrevendo a sua variável `p` (o array inicial) ao chamar cada elemento dentro dele como `p` também.

Dessa forma, na linha `for q in p:`, `p` não é mais o seu array inicial, mas sim um de seus elementos. Como os elementos do array são números (do tipo `numpy.float64`), e números não são iteráveis, você vê o erro.

Simplesmente escolha outro nome para a variável no seu loop para corrigir isso, por exemplo:

```
for elemento_01 in p:
    for elemento_02 in p:
        if elemento_01 != elemento_02:
            arrFreq.append(elemento_01 - elemento_02)
```

Answer (score 0):

Este erro estar sendo retornado porque você esta utilizando o objeto "p" do primeiro for que é um objeto do tipo float64 (que não é um objeto iterável) para a iteração do segundo for:

```
for p in p: 
    for q in p:
```

Pode usar algo parecido com o código abaixo:

```
x = 0

while(x < len(p) - 1):
    arrFreq.append(p[x] - p[x + 1])
    x+=1
```

Onde a variável x é utilizada apenas como um contador, utilizo um while para percorrer até o penúltimo elemento do array e comparo sempre o elemento com seu sucessor.